# .trigger() won't fire custom events

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Go to any page with jQuery. Open the console. Type in this command:

```
monitorEvents(document);
```

this will show you all events that the document sees. If you move your mouse around the page, you'll see the `mousemove` events.

Now type in:

```
$("body").trigger("click");
```

You should see the `click` event show up in the console (from `monitorEvents`).

Now try this command:

```
$("body").trigger("custom");
```

The event does now show up in the console. For me at least it doesn't.

It seems if I use trigger to fire a normal event, it works, but for custom events, its not being raised. Why?

Comment: jQuery implements custom events internally, not through the browser's event event processing mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

For almost the same reason that `$('body').trigger('mouseup');` shows nothing; there is no event listener for that particular event.

You need to attach the event listener first. jQuery constructs its own type of event objects.

```
$('body').on('whatever', function (e) {
  window.console.log(e);
});
```

Now `$('body').trigger('whatever');` will work.

---

If you'd like to dive into some vanilla JavaScript here's the documentation for events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Answer (score -1):

You probably just need to [construct an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) first. Try:

`var customEvent = new Event("custom");`